# Using regex to validate input data with potentially repeated pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to use Regex to validate the form field data in javascript. The accepted patterns are for a single item, `Org-1234` or for multiple, `Org-1234, Org-56789`. For multiple items, they have to be separated by comma (with potential space around it). The matching should be case insensitive.

I came up with this regex: `/^(org-\d+)([ ,](org-\d+))*/i`, however it only matches the first capture group. How could I make it work with an optional repeated pattern, i.e., if there is more character outside of the first match group, it has to conform with the same pattern, separated by comma?

Comment: That's because `[ ,]` only matches one character. Add a `+` after it, like `[ ,]+`. Then it will match one or more of space and comma.

Comment: Good catch! Even with that, this would still not work with something like `org-123, org-` as it matches the first group.

Comment: Add a `$` at the end, then it must match to the end (or not at all).

Comment: *they have to be **separated by comma** (with **potential space around it**)* to do this, you need to use eg: [`^org-\d+(?: *, *org-\d+)*$`](https://regex101.com/r/FzU5DZ/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another idea may be to split the string an test the resulting trimmed and lowercased items for starting with `org` and having one or morge numbers at the end. Something like:

```js
const value1 = `Org-1234, Org-56789`;
const value2 = `Org-1234, Org-`;
const value3 = `Org-1234`;
const value4 = `NOPE-1234`;
const value5 = `Org-1, Org-2`;

const validate = t => 
  t.startsWith(`org`) && /\d+$/.test(t);
const _isValid = term => {
  const _t = term.split(`,`)
    .map(v => v.trim().toLowerCase());
  return _t.length === _t.filter(validate).length;
};

console.log(isValid(value1));
console.log(isValid(value2));
console.log(isValid(value3));
console.log(isValid(value4));
console.log(isValid(value5));
```

Or to get rid of any regular expression:

```js
const values2Test = [
  `Org-1234, Org-56789`, `Org-1234, Org-`, `Org-1234`,
  `NOPE-1234`, `Org-1, Org-2`,`, Org-22`, ``, `dont-know`,
  223, `    oRg-198762,  ORG-2098`];
const yn = v => !v ? `` : ``;
const isValid = str => !`${str}`.split(`,`)
  .map( v => v.trim().split(`-`) )
  .find( ([org, number]) => 
    (org || `!`).toLowerCase() !== `org` || isNaN(+(number || undefined)) );
// test all values    
values2Test.forEach( v => console.log(`${yn(isValid(v))} ${v}`) );
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: will accept this answer since it's more straightforward/readable than trying to come up with a clever regex, thanks!

Comment: Hi @Liumx31, glad I could help. I've added a function that doesn't use any regular expression ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following `(?<=^|,\s)(org-\d+(?=,\s|$))+`
Check here https://regex101.com/r/tdB9If/1